# Building an array with "secure" point arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to build a C ++ array overflow protected.
I built a very nice system(using class+template) that protects access to the following form
Let's say I set

```
ProtectedArray<int,15> A;
```

So if I try to go to `A [16]` like this:

```
A[16]=10;
```

he throws me an exception.
I want to create a situation that if I try to do

```
int * a = &A;
a += 16;
a = 13;
```

Be thrown an exception, is it possible at all to do this? (Alleged that moment that I  put the array Pointer I do not have "control" on it)...

*I implemented in the class overlouding of [](so i will be able to call A[10] ), And &( to get the pointer to the base)

Comment: No it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially when you convert the type to an integer pointer you loose all control over that type - it become exactly like a standard c++ int* (which obviously doesn't include bounds checking).